# Visual Studio 2015 settings for generated pdb (debug symbols) file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, debug-symbols, pdb-files

Are there settings that affect the pdb file generated when VS2015 (or earlier versions) compiles a library?

Specifically, I am wanting it to *not* have the full file path.
For example, given the stack trace

```
System.Exception: An exception has occurred.
  at Project.ClassA.MethodB() in C:\Sources\Solution\Project\ClassA.cs:line 100
```

I would prefer it be

```
System.Exception: An exception has occurred.
  at Project.ClassA.MethodB() in Project\ClassA.cs:line 100
```

Edit:
The reason we are looking for this ability is because "C:\Sources\Solution\Project" is meaningless on the system where the application will eventually be tested/deployed, or even on some of our other developers' systems.

We could just not deploy the symbols at all, but they help provide more useful info when exceptions are logged.

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDB is a debug information file that Visual Studio uses. Go to `Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols` and select checkbox "Microsoft Symbol Servers".
Visual Studio will download PDB's automatically.

And as far as I know the fully qualified name of the file is how Visual studio is able to find the file. I'm not sure nor have i ever heard of a way to change that behavior except for maybe putting project into the same directory as Visual Studio. Although I'm pretty sure it would still display the same way. I would need to see the full error code to provide more information that that.

Comment: I'm not talking about making the debugging symbols available to Visual Studio, I'm talking about changing the contents of the debugging symbols generated by Visual Studio when I compile my project.

Comment: Then no, as far as i know that is not possible as Visual Studio uses the absolute path to the associated file.

Comment: I find it odd it uses the absolute path as opposed to a relative path using the library's project folder as the root, since the point of debugging symbols is to provide info to *any* debugger hooked into the compiled library, regardless of where it is deployed/running from.